# Свой браузер на движке Chromium в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, браузер

Доброго времени суток!

Стало интересно: в Visual Studio можно сделать свой браузер на движке IE, а можно ли вместо него использовать Chromium?

Comment: Да, конечно, можно.

Comment: прочитал вышенаписанное,может я криво выразился,имеется ввиду,что когда используешь WebBrowser, то прилепляется ИЕ, а возможно ли вместо него заставить работать хромиум? Спасибо)

Comment: @Kuppers - зная MS я отвечу с 99% вероятностью что нет

Comment: ну тут,как говорится,о вкусах не спорят,однако мне ИЕ не очень люб)) на базе хромиума вообще больше всех понравился coolnovo своим огромным количеством функционалом,однако не могу понять почему не сохраняет пароли в отличие от гуглхрома,хотя галка там стоит где надо,непонятно)

Comment: @Kuppers - я не считаю IE лучшим в мире браузером, LOL, отнюдь. Я лишь описал то, как все видит MS. Мое убеждение - IE must die

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю @AlexWindHope :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) посмотрите.

Comment: интересно,похоже это то,что нужно,благодарю

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ как верный, если он вам помог.

Comment: я бы с радостью,но видимо ограничение моей репутации не позволяет ставить лайки

Comment: не "лайк", а "принять ответ". галочка такая.

Answer (score 6):

Если для вас ключевым является использование браузерного движка WebKit, который используется в хромиуме, то гляньте тут: [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php?p=2)

Comment: спасибо,почитаю